# How to convert integers to characters in PHP

Tags: php

How to create a function for converting integers to characters in PHP like this:

```
'A' => 0,
'B' => 1,
'C' => 2,
'D' => 3,
'E' => 4,
'F' => 5,
'G' => 6,
'H' => 7,
'I' => 8,
'J' => 9
```

If number is 100, then it should generate BAA.

The A, B, C... are just an example. I am trying to encrypt the numbers with a code.

I need this to work with some word like

```
0 => zero
1 => one
```

etc

But when I give number 10, it should output `onezero`.

Comment: $character = chr($integer+65); This is a standard function of almost every computer language ever invented

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: and ORD() is the reverse

Comment: You meant ASCII value something?

Comment: Will the letters be uppercase letters only?

Comment: Its not ASCII, but will convert to upper case letters.

Comment: You want replace numbers in a string with characters in your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$list=array('A' => 0,
'B' => 1,
'C' => 2,
'D' => 3,
'E' => 4,
'F' => 5,
'G' => 6,
'H' => 7,
'I' => 8,
'J' => 9);
 $num=1234; //your value
 $temp='';
 $arr_num=str_split ($num);
foreach($arr_num as $data)
{
$temp.=array_search($data,$list);
}
$num=$temp;
echo $num; // here we get BCDE
?>
```

Comment: wouldn't `$list=array('A','B',..);` then `$temp.=$list[$data];` be better?

Comment: `array('A','B',..);` is short for `array(0=>'A', 1=>'B'..);` so you can add anything as long as its a valid index

Answer (score 16):

Simple try like this

```
    $letter = chr($i+65);
    echo $letter;
```

gives 'A'

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$number = 100;
$len = strlen($number);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) {
    echo printAlphabet(substr($number,$i,1));
}
function printAlphabet($pos) {
    $letter = chr($pos+65);
    return $letter;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
$numarr=array('A' => 0, 'B' => 1, 'C' => 2);
$narr = array_flip($numarr);

$num = 100;
$arr = str_split($num);

$str = '';
foreach($arr as $s)
   $str .= $narr[$s];
echo $str . "\n"; //BAA
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/3XqoZ7

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, is having a function that returns the position of a letter in the alphabet you can do it by this:

```
<?php
    function chartonumber($char) {
        return ord(strtolower($char)) - 96;
    }
    echo chartonumber('A')."\n";
    echo chartonumber('b')."\n";
    echo chartonumber('E')."\n";
?>
```

This will print:

```
1
2
5
```

Which is the positions of letters A, b and E respectively.

How it works:
- It makes sure to make the letter lower case.
- it converts it to an ascii int.
- Subtracts the previous 96 ascii table characters.

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

I created an abstract function :

```
    private function getCoordinates($row, $col){
            $letter = $this->getLetter($col);
            return $letter.$row;
    }

    private function getLetter($col){
            // 64+1 = 65 ==>> "A"
            $letter = '';
            if ($col<=26){
                    $letter = chr(64+$col);
            } else {
                    $newCol = intdiv($col, 26);
                    $resCol = ($col % 26);
                    $letter = $this->getLetter($newCol).chr(64+$resCol);
            }
            return $letter;
    }

TEST:
la letra para fila:7 y columna:1 es : A7
la letra para fila:7 y columna:26 es : Z7
la letra para fila:7 y columna:27 es : AA7
la letra para fila:7 y columna:23455756 es : AYHMVL7
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$stack = array("A", "B");
array_push($stack, "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H","I","J");
print_r($stack);
?>
```